# Add Itinerary Remark SABRE

Tags: api, soap, sabre

**While i am sending Add Itinerary Remark in sabre FLIGHT API Request it's through Error (Business logic Error). Please Suggest me**

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
     <soap-env:Header>
         <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb='http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader'>
             <eb:From>
                 <eb:PartyId eb:type='urn:x12.org.IO5:01'>sabre@example.com</eb:PartyId>
             </eb:From>
             <eb:To>
                 <eb:PartyId eb:type='urn:x12.org.IO5:01'>webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
             </eb:To>
             <eb:ConversationId>1500986572sabre@example.com</eb:ConversationId>
             <eb:Service eb:type='OTA'>Air</eb:Service>
             <eb:Action>AddRemarkLLSRQ</eb:Action>
             <eb:CPAID>IPCC</eb:CPAID>
             <eb:MessageData>
                 <eb:MessageId>mid:1500986572sabre@example.com</eb:MessageId>
                 <eb:Timestamp>2017-07-25T12-42-52Z</eb:Timestamp>
                 <eb:TimeToLive>2017-07-25T12-42-52Z</eb:TimeToLive>
             </eb:MessageData>
         </eb:MessageHeader>
         <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext'>
             <wsse:UsernameToken>
                 <wsse:Username>USER</wsse:Username>
                 <wsse:Password>PASS</wsse:Password>
                 <Organization>IPCC</Organization>
                 <Domain>Default</Domain>
             </wsse:UsernameToken>
             <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3250684970584119419!1379810!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
         </wsse:Security>
     </soap-env:Header>
     <soap-env:Body>
         <AddRemarkRQ xmlns='http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' ReturnHostCommand='false' Version='2.1.0'>
             <RemarkInfo>
                 <FOP_Remark>
                     <CC_Info>
                         <PaymentCard Code="VI" ExpireDate="2022-3" Number="4111111111111111" />
                     </CC_Info>
                 </FOP_Remark>
                 <Remark Type="General">
                     <Text>Swadesh Dash,nandan@gmail.com,8989852356</Text>
                 </Remark>
                 <Remark Type="Client Address">
                     <Text>Swadesh Dash,8989852356, nandan@gmail.com</Text>
                 </Remark>
             </RemarkInfo>
         </AddRemarkRQ>
     </soap-env:Body>
 </soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would help knowing what is the business error you got, but I see:

- `ExpireDate="2022-3"` - I presume that it does not take `3` as month, it should be `03`
- In the other 2 remarks there `@` signs which likely are characters not supported in remarks.

For an improved response, please post the business error.

Answer (score 0):

I can get only one possible reason and that is "Special Characters not allowed by Sabre"
And you have used @ in remarks.

Special Characters which are not allowed are @,$,%,&,(,),[,],{,},<,>,?,=,+,;,Σ,_,' etc.